A non-decreasing transfinite sequence must become stationary?
Premise: I am very unfamiliar with ordinals. I am trying to understand a proof that makes use of them, and so I am reading a bit about the topic, but it might be that my question is very imprecise or that it does not make sense at all. Apologies in case...
Consider a transfinite sequence $(x_\beta)$ or real numbers in $[0,1]$, labelled by the countable ordinals. (I guess one can say that the labels are in $\omega_1$?) Assume that such a sequence is non-decreasing (with respect to the ordinal ordering for the labels, and the standard order on $[0,1]$, namely if $\gamma>\beta$ then $x_\gamma\geq x_\beta$). Is it true that such sequence must become stationary (i.e., there is an ordinal $\beta$ such that for any $\gamma>\beta$ we have $x_\gamma = x_\beta$)?
I really do not know where to start to decide whether or not this is true...

A strictly increasing sequence cannot be stationary. You want to ask something else I guess.

yes... it's just non-decreasing of course... I'll fix it, thanks for pointing it out

I think you want to ask whether there is a strictly increasing sequence ...

See Are there any known uncountable transfinite increasing sequences of real numbers? AND Is there any well-ordered uncountable set of real numbers under the original ordering?

@DaveL.Renfro thanks! So in practice I can have only countably many indices $\beta_n$ such that $x_{\beta_n+1}>x_{\beta_n}$. But does this automatically imply stationarity? I mean, I guess I could still have a countable sequence of indices that is not bounded from above in $\omega_1$?

But does this automatically imply stationarity? --- Yes, there is something to add here. Something along the lines of $\ldots$ Consider the subset of the ordinal indices where strict increase occurs. We know this is countable, so there are only countably many ordinals involved, and the supremum of countably many ordinals is countable.

I see! thank you, I might write an answer to the question later to summarise it, unless you want to do it.

Go ahead and write an answer. However, this might get closed as a duplicate, so if you write an answer maybe see if you can add details and/or exposition that goes beyond existing answers, maybe something that provides a lot of hand-holding for someone new to the subject (partly because doing it this way helps better with your own learning).
